# How do I get a signal in the main process to start an action?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-vlc

I'm writing a player program in python.

The effect I want to achieve is to get a signal after playing a song and then go to the next song.

some code:

```
def end_call_back(event):
    print('call:', 'a song finished')


if "__main__" == __name__:
    app = App()
    app.player.play('sample1.mp4')
    app.player.add_callback(vlc.EventType.MediaPlayerStopped, end_call_back)

    **# Here , I want to received a signal to play the next song.**

    app.mainloop()
```

now, I can get the sentence in the console，“a song finished”

What should I do next in the main process to get a signal to play the next song?

Comment: Wouldn't it be the same thing you did to play the first song? I would think if you mean for it to keep playing, I would add it to your `end_call_back` delegate code.

Comment: @BenY, I tried.  Simply adding a sentence `app.player.play('next-song.mp4')`  in `end_call_back` delegate code.  But it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't know what framework you are using, as you did not add the tag, so I am unable to provide any way to inject actions into the main loop.

Comment: @BenY Python-3.7, python-vlc, tkinter.  If you can give some advice, thank you in advance.

Comment: If `app` is an instance of custom class inherited from `Tk()`, then try calling `app.after(10, app.player.play, "sample2.mp4")` inside `end_call_back()`.